# Can root create the directory if not exists while backups

Tags: linux, shell-script, centos-5

I am getting the databases from mysql and my database name is  username_something.
I am getting the username and then puting the respective backups in corresponding folders like

```
tar bala bla  /backups/sql/username/username_something.tar.sql.gz
```

The problem is system worrks if i have the folder username already there but for new databases if get the error like unknown file path.

How can i do that if username folder is not there it should be created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mkdir before the tar command to create the directory.  If multiple dirs in the path may be missing, you can use the -p flag.  Using -p will also suppress the error if the directory already exists.

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir -p /backups/sql/username && tar ...
```